# Apache htaccess rewriterule issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule in htaccess

```
 RewriteRule ^noticias/?$ /index.php?view=pagination&ptype=noticias [L]
```

But the problem is that if I put some spaces in the URL, like this .. I can access the page normally.

```
 http://gamesite.org/noticias     /
```

I do not know what I do to block it.

without `/` the browser removes the spaces. but the problem is that I need this bar, because of paging on my site. `Ex: /noticias/1/`

Here is my htaccess file http://pastebin.com/gwtZGaGv

Comment: Just use ^noticias, don't add the trailing / or $ since you are not "Rewriting" it you be okay

Comment: Cristopher. I tested and it did not work :/

Comment: @robsondias do you want to internally redirect or a 301 redirect ?

Comment: @robsondias as an addition I have just tried your rule and it only allow spaces when you're not using the `/` and that because the browser itself removes the space by default when you click go or press enter.

Comment: @Prix yes .. without `/` the browser removes the spaces. but the problem is that I need this bar, because of paging on my site. `Ex: /noticias/1/`

Comment: @robsondias What other rules do you have on your .htaccess it seems something else may be overwriting it.

Comment: @robsondias use the [**Edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17824563/edit) link and update to your question, will take a look ASAP.